# Arduino or Raspberry Pi?

Tags: c++, arduino, raspberry-pi

Basically I have developed an application in C++ and have four classes. The functionality of the code works well with a "main" interface that just outputs the result.

The application I've built is in [speech recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_recognition), and I need to demonstrate it using either an Arduino or a Raspberry Pi and will include three LEDS that will turn on depending on the result. Here's the problem / Questions...

- I don't want to change the classes in order to suite a different platform. It works well how it is, and I would just like this as a demonstration to how the code / functionality will work. Would this be possible using Arduino / Raspberry Pi?
- I don't want the Arduino / Raspberry Pi to physically handle the ([WAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV)) file, because I need to change the conditions. Instead, I just want to send the (WAV) file to the device and then using the code I have already built which handles the WAV file. Is this possible AND would the Arduino or Raspberry Pi be the better choice?

I hope I have explained this in enough details.

P.S. I have included the C++ tag because it DOES kind of relate to C++.

Comment: Arduino or Raspberry PI? How about TI Launchpad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is already written in C++ I would recommend the Raspberry Pi as it has much more capabilities than an Arduino and I am not sure if C++ code is compatible with an Arduino (the ones I own support ATMEL assembly, C# on netduino, and some C/Java hybrid so I'm not sure). If you want to to run on a Pi you would just have to write some code for the LED lighting which there are examples of on the net already and the Pi can run an entire Linux OS to help you debug any issues you might have (on top of being pretty fun to mess around with).

Also for handling the .wav file transfer the Pi would handle it better as you have more variety in how you choose to handle the file (place it on the SD card, network, etc...).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)! So just to clarify, I can still use my classes and it would compile on the Raspberry pi? I don't want to change these. I know I would have to write some code for the LEDS and I'm alright doing that, just changing what I've spent months coding is the main worry here! I think I'm going to go for the Pi :)!

Comment: @Phorce If your C++ code is Linux based and doesn't include any architecture specific stuff then you can easily satisfy library dependencies on the Pi (provided they are ARM friendly). For you this means that you probably don't have to modify any code :)

Comment: I use g++ to compile my code and I compile it on a mac so it should be okay, correct? And great stuff :)! In terms of portability, once the code has been compiled etc.. Is it easy to "build it into a unit" which then can be taken places to show off? haha thanks for your help :)!

Comment: @Phorce Yeah for the most part you should be fine since most mac compatible stuff also works on linux (as long as its POSIX compliant :P). What exactly do you mean by build into a unit though? If you mean ARM executable for any raspberry pi, then yes.

Comment: Hard to explain, but, basically, the ability to hide the board.. And take it to show people, basically, plugging it in somewhere else and pulling the files off the servers and compiling / running the code etc..

Comment: @Phorce Yeah you can buy a pre built enclosure for your Pi if you really want to hide the board. It support s-video out as well as HDMI and has an ethernet port so choose whatever works for you or you can ssh into it.

Comment: Just ordered it :)! Thanks once again for your help, wish me luck with it haha!